# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'MyComplex' and 'MyComplex'

Tags: python, python-3.x

That's my console output:

```
1.00-1.00i
-5.00+9.00i
14.00+22.00i
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "complex.py", line 33, in <module>
    print( m / n )
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'MyComplex' and 'MyComplex'
```

I don't know what's wrong with my code for me everything seems right. I've been trying to fix this error but I don't get why it isn't working.

Here is my code:

```py
class MyComplex:

    def __init__(self, re, im):
        self.re = re
        self.im = im

    def __add__(self, x):
        return MyComplex(self.re + x.re, self.im + x.im)

    def __sub__(self, x):
        return MyComplex( self.re - x.re, self.im - x.im)

    def __mul__(self, x):
        re = self.re * x.re - self.im * x.im
        im = self.re * x.im + self.im * x.re
        return MyComplex(re, im)

    def __div__(self, x):
        r = float(x.re ** 2 + x.im ** 2)
        return MyComplex((self.re * x.re + self.im * x.im) / r, \
                         (self.im * x.re - self.re * x.im) / r)

    def __str__(self):
        if(self.im >= 0):
            return '%2.2f+%2.2fi' % (self.re, self.im)
        return '%2.2f%2.2fi' % (self.re, self.im)

m = MyComplex(-2,4)
n = MyComplex(3,-5)
print( m + n )
print( m - n )
print( m * n )
print( m / n )
```

Comment: Works fine on my machine. (Python 2.7)

Comment: As an aside: Did you know python has got native support for complex numbers? `(-2 + 4j)*(3 - 5j)` => `(14+22j)` :D

Comment: Yeah I know this function but we should do it like that. On my machine it shows the error above im using python3.5.1

Comment: Ok i got it sorry for this bad Title and that I didn't found the topic
thanks for your support (: